# Roxy Fileman with TinyMCE 5 using file_picker_callback

Tags: javascript, tinymce, roxy-fileman

I'm trying to **upgrade** TinyMCE from ver.4 **to ver.5**, but the function file_browser_callback has been replaced by **file_picker_callback** that has completely different parameters:

TinyMCE v.4

```
file_browser_callback: function (fieldId, value, type, win) {
    browseFiles(value, type, function (fileUrl) {
      win.document.getElementById(fieldId).value = fileUrl;
    });
}
```

TinyMCE v.5

```
file_picker_callback: function (callback, value, meta) {
   browseFiles(value, meta.filetype, function (fileUrl) {
      callback(fileUrl);
   });
}
```

I'm able to retrieve only the old parameter **type** that in v.5 is in **meta.filetype**, but **not the other parameters**, **field_name** and **win**, necessary to Roxy Fileman.

and here is my full implementation using v.4:

```
function initEditor(selector) {
            tinymce.init({
                selector: selector,
                plugins: "paste,link,lists,advlist,image,table,contextmenu,media,fullscreen",
                paste_as_text: true,
                menubar: false,
                language: 'en',
                forced_root_block: 'div',
                encoding: 'xml', //used to solve Dangerous Request.Form exception - Seems it's not enough alone.
                block_formats: 'Paragraph=p;Header 1=h1;Header 2=h2;Header 3=h3',
                toolbar: 'undo redo | styleselect | bold italic underline strikethrough | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist | link unlink | image | media | fullscreen',
                file_browser_callback: RoxyFileBrowser,
                inline: false,
                setup: function (editor) {
                    editor.on('change', function (e) {
                        //saved = false;
                        //$("#btn-save").css('border', '2px solid #D85145');
                        //$("#btn-save").html('SAVE');
                    });
                }
            });
        }

    function RoxyFileBrowser(field_name, url, type, win) {
        var cmsURL = roxyFileman;  // script URL - use an absolute path!
        if (cmsURL.indexOf("?") < 0) {
            cmsURL = cmsURL + "?type=" + type;
        }
        else {
            cmsURL = cmsURL + "&type=" + type;
        }
        cmsURL += '&input=' + field_name + '&value=' + win.document.getElementById(field_name).value;
        tinyMCE.activeEditor.windowManager.open({
            file: cmsURL,
            title: 'MVAM - Media File Repository',
            width: 850, // Your dimensions may differ - toy around with them!
            height: 650,
            resizable: "yes",
            plugins: "media",
            inline: "yes", // This parameter only has an effect if you use the inlinepopups plugin!
            close_previous: "no"
        }, {
                window: win,
                input: field_name
            });
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: I am having the same problem as you. Has your problem been solved yet?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a new way of creating dialog windows with external content with TinyMCE5: [URL dialog](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/ui-components/urldialog/) and this method differs from old one in v.4.

You don’t need parameters **win** and **field_name** anymore. Earlier Roxy Fileman used them to put there newly retrieved value. But now you must just send this value to callback and TinyMCE will do the rest. So the new code that works is:

```
function RoxyFileBrowser(callback, value, type) {
    var roxyFileman = '/fileman/index.html';
    roxyFileman += (roxyFileman.indexOf("?")<0 ? "?" : "&") + "type=" + type.filetype;
    roxyFileman += '&input=' + field_name + '&value=' + win.document.getElementById(field_name).value;
    if(value)
        roxyFileman += '&value=' + value; // a link to already chosen image if it exists
    if(tinyMCE.activeEditor.settings.language)
        roxyFileman += '&langCode=' + tinyMCE.activeEditor.settings.language;

    const instanceApi = tinyMCE.activeEditor.windowManager.openUrl({
        title: 'Roxy Fileman',
        url: roxyFileman,
        width: 850, 
        height: 650,
        onMessage: function(dialogApi, details) {
            callback(details.content);
            instanceApi.close();
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

A new tough part was to get back the value from the dialog into RoxyFileBrowser function. And it solves by using messages in function `FileSelected` in *js/custom.js*:

```
function FileSelected(file){
  window.parent.postMessage({
    mceAction: 'FileSelected',
    content: file.fullPath
  }, '*');
}
```

To get this work you need to set `"INTEGRATION": "custom"` in *conf.json*

Comment: Helpful answer, maybe mentioning that ` file_browser_callback` is replaced by `file_picker_callback` in v5 would save others some time.

Comment: Not entirely sure what this answer means. The function is still using the field_name argument while you removed it from the argument list, so it simply results in an undefined error.

Besides this, roxyman filebrowser will stop working properly using the function you wrote.

Comment: Also, the 3rd line, on the function RoxyFileBrowser() should be commented/removed in order to work and avoid the undefined error.